# How to set the value to my elements

Tags: html, css, responsive, units-of-measurement

How to set the value to my margin property when I want to responsive it?
I mean, if I want to set value to width, for example to 50%

So what if I want to set with margin? I have to set it in `em` is it right?
or font size: `em`
because pixel is a absolute unit but em is a relative unit, is that right?

Answer (score -1):

Google is your friend.

Responsive design is based off of certain pixel breakpoints where you decide to adjust components.

For example:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      body {background-color: green;}
 }
```

This will change the background color of the `body` element to `green` when the browser window's width is `<=` 500px.

[The Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) is a good place to start. Take a read and let us know if you have more specific questions.

Welcome to SO.

Comment: I know that but When I want to create a template I use px unit for all elements like : margins-width-paddings-fontsize everything

Comment: But now I want to responsive my web page and somebody said that you have to use em and % units for your elements

Comment: @ali `em`s are based off of `font-size` and percentages are based off of dimensions (browser width, parent element dimensions, etc.). People do recommend using `em`s on margins and paddings, but I would recommend you stick with percentages for dimensions and `em`s for fonts. It's a personal preference, really. Hopefully that helps...

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much bro